# Why does \\ not return a new line in an equation?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

```
\begin{equation*}\label{eq:pareto mle2}
A_0 = \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x} \right ) "\\\" <br>
 - \frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T} \right ),
\end{equation*}
```

This is my code why `\\` does not go to new line?
How should I make it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides quite a few environments that help typeset equations that need to be split across two or more lines. The `align*` environment may be particularly suitable for the case at hand. In the code posted below, note the use of the `&` symbol to state the alignment points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}\label{eq:pareto mle2}
A_0 &=   \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}} \,{}_2 F_1\biggl( r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;
         \frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x} \biggr)\\
&\quad - \frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}   \,{}_2 F_1\biggl( r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;
         \frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T}   \biggr),
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: Note the close similarity of the outputs produced by the *single* `align*` environment in this answer and the *nested pair* of `equation*`/`multlined` environments in [@HarishKumar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194237/5001).

Comment: Good answer, thanks! Small detail: couldn't you get rid of the `\quad` by moving the`&` to immediately after the equal sign?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken - Thanks. The reason I used `\quad` to indent the second row  was to follow a common typographic equation: to indicate visually that the second row is a continuation of the equation that began on the first row, the `-` symbol is deliberately not set immediately below the `=` symbol in the first row.

Comment: oh, I think you misunderstood me - I completely agree that it should show up in that way. I'm just saying that you could avoid having to use `\quad` by moving the `&` of the first row so that you get `A_0 =&`. That way you still get the same output, but without having to include `\quad` in the second row.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken -- Look closely at the spacing around the `=` symbol if you write `=&` instead of `&=`: The spacing becomes highly asymmetric -- rather nonstandard! That's why the user guide of the `amsmath` package recommends writing `&=`. :-)

Comment: ooh, I see - didn't notice that :). Thanks again!

Comment: When ```align``` is used (without the ```*```) and there is a linebreak a new number is given to the new line. So if I wish to only have a numbering on my first line inside the environment how can I do this ? Is it possible?

Comment: @Broxigar - When using an `align` or `gather` environment, you can issue `\notag` directives for those lines which shouldn't receive an equation number.

Comment: @Mico much obliged. works like a charm!

Answer (score 61):

Both `equation` and  `equation*` do not allow multi lined expressions. Use `aligned` from `amsmath`, inside `equation*` to break in to many lines. If alignment is not needed, you can use `gathered` (instead of `aligned`) as suggested by Mico.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}\label{eq:pareto mle2}
  \begin{aligned}
A_0 = \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x} \right ) \\
 - \frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T} \right ),
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Or use `multlined` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}\label{eq:pareto mle2}
  \begin{multlined}
A_0 = \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x} \right ) \\
 - \frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T} \right ),
 \end{multlined}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `split` might be fruitful here, particularly with numbered equations. Of course, `multlined` is not needed, as `multline*` suffices.

Comment: how to use equation* for numbered equations ?

Comment: @StanGeo - By design, the "starred" environments -- `equation*`, `align*`, etc -- do not create equation numbers. Use the "non-starred" environments -- `equation`, `align`, etc -- to create numbered equations.

Comment: In fact, would `split` might be more syntactically fitting, given that there is only one equation here? As *The LaTeX Companion*, 3ed, puts it, "When a simple alignment is needed within a single multiple-line equation, the `split` environment is almost always the best choice."

Answer (score 24):

There is an easy way to make `\\` works in equation (change line):

```
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}
```

Change it to

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{l}
    a = \\ 
    b
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: A side-effect -- possibly unpleasant -- of this approach is that the contents of the `array` environment will be processed in text-style math mode instead of in display-style math mode.

Answer (score 8):

To obtain multi-lined expressions with equation number written beside, use the following code;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\begin{aligned}
A_0 = \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x} \right ) \\
 - \frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{}_2F_1\left(r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T} \right ),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to add the number at the last line of the equation, load the `amsmath` package with the option `tbtags`:

     \usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

Comment: `mathtools` package inserts the `amsmath` package, so no need to call the package separately....

Comment: At least in Overleaf, using align inside equation does the trick but causes an annoying error. Simply replace align by split and you are done. For more information check this link (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning%20equations%20with%20amsmath#:~:text=Inside%20the%20equation%20environment%2C%20use,the%20equations%20are%20vertically%20aligned.)

Comment: @AxelMancino yours was the only useful comment I found on this page (but I guess not everyone uses overleaf..)

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but without really satisfactory answers, in my opinion.

I'd go with `multline`, which has been introduced exactly for cases such as the present one. On the other hand, also `split` may be considered worth of use in this case, particularly in the third example, where the alignment is on the right, underlining the similarity between the two parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{leftidx}

\newcommand{\hg}[3][F]{\mathop{\leftidx{_{#2}}{#1}{_{#3}}\kern-\scriptspace}}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{\texttt{multline}}

\begin{multline}
A_0 =
  \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x}
  \biggr) \\
-\frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T}
  \biggr),
\end{multline}

\subsection*{\texttt{split} 1}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A_0 &=
  \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x}
  \biggr) \\
&\qquad
-\frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T}
  \biggr),
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\subsection*{\texttt{split} 2}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A_0 &=
  \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x}
  \biggr) \\
&
-\frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T}
  \biggr),
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\subsection*{\texttt{split} 3}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A_0 =
  \frac{1}{(\alpha+t_x)^{r+s+x}} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + t_x}
  \biggr) \\
-\frac{1}{(\alpha+T)^{r+s+x}}{} \hg{2}{1} \biggl(
    r+s+x,x+1;r+s+x+1;\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha + T}
  \biggr)\makebox[0pt][l]{,}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Points to note:

1. instead of `{}_2F_1` that produces misaligned subscripts, I defined a command `\hg` (for *h*yper*g*eometric);
2. `\left` and `\right` have been replaced by `\biggl` and `\biggr`;
3. if no numbering is wanted just add `*` to the name of the outer environment (`multline*` or `equation*`).

[image]

Comment: +1 though my favourite would be a (fourth) `split` with `={}&`.